# Deriving a variable type based on another variable type in C++

Tags: c++, templates, hash

I'm working on the implementation of hash functions, mainly based on the Carter and Wegman trick. Based on the size of the input space, the prime used needs to be long enough to make a robust hash, e.g. if I want a hash for uint32_t, I'll use the Mersenne prime 2^61-1 and therefore I need a uint64_t; for a uint16_t I also need uint64_t, etc.

So far I've implemented it as a template with two types, but since I know before hand which types go with which ones, it would be more convenient if I could implement it as a template with a single type.

So far [I have something like](https://github.com/esterl/sketches/blob/master/hash.h):

```
    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    class Hash_CW2: public Hash<T1>{
        protected:
            T2 seeds[2];
            [...]
            void init(unsigned B, T2 seed0, T2 seed1);

        public:
            Hash_CW2(unsigned B, T2 seed0, T2 seed1);
            [...]
            virtual unsigned element(T1 j);
};
```

And I'd like to have something like:

```
    template<typename T1, typename T2=GET_TYPE(T1)>
    class Hash_CW2: public Hash<T1>{
        [...]
};
```

Any idea how to do it? Is it possible?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How about using [template specialization](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html)? Possibly combined with inheritance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using template specialization you could do something like:

```
template <typename T>
struct hash_type_for;

template <>
struct hash_type_for<uint16_t>
{ using type = uint64_t; };

template <>
struct hash_type_for<uint32_t>
{ using type = uint64_t; };

template <typename T>
using hash_type_for_t = typename hash_type_for<T>::type;
```

Then use it like this:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2 = hash_type_for_t<T1>>
class Hash_CW2: public Hash<T1>{
```

Or if you want `T2` to be calculated solely from `T1` and don't want the user to be able to change it:

```
template<typename T1>
class Hash_CW2: public Hash<T1>{
    using hash_type = hash_type_for_t<T1>;
```